# UPDATE a table based on a linked TABLE using a JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I would like to update a field for a `parent` based on a linked table `baby`. It needs to set the `parent.optin` value to 1 if any of the linked babies have `baby.optin` = 1

This is the query I have at the moment where I'm trying to run the query for one parent (id of 11)

```
UPDATE parent p
INNER JOIN baby b
    ON p.id = b.parent_id
    AND b.optin = 1
SET p.optin=b.optin
WHERE p.id = 11
```

The parent has 2 babies, one has opted in and one hasn't. At the moment my query is not setting p.optin to 1.

Example data:

Parent

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | optin |
+----+-------+-------+
| 11 | dave  | 0     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Baby

```
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
| id | parent_id | name    | optin |
+----+-----------+---------+-------+
| 2  | 1         | jane    | 0     |
| 3  | 1         | freddie | 1     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

With the above data, I would like to set the Parent.optin value to 1, because freddie has optin 1. If freddie's optin value was 0, then parent.optin would also be 0.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to ignore (not update) if _any_ related row is `baby.optin = 0`  or ignore (not update) only if _all_ related `baby.optin = 0`?  It would help considerably if you include some sample rows from the two tables, together with a sample of what the modified `parent` table would be following the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have updated my question with sample rows which hopefully makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try this. If you do not get solve your error then let me know.

```
UPDATE parent p, baby b
INNER JOIN baby b ON p.id = b.parent_id
SET p.optin=b.optin
WHERE p.id = 11 AND b.optin = 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't work either. In fact isn't that query the same as what I was trying? Is there a difference moving the `b.optin = 1`from the INNER JOIN to the WHERE?